# Leaflet adding markers on map and data security

Tags: javascript, security

I'm looking into using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/index.html) to make maps and place markers in an internal application (i.e. not a web-site, but a simple desktop application), but I'm wondering which data is sent and which is not. Do the following command send any data or is it only plotted locally?

```
 marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(mymap);
```

Needless to say, I want to keep my data confidential and not send it away over the web.
(If this is the case, then any recommendation on a good alternatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all local (I use leaflet offline all the time). If you want to check the source code for markers and look for yourself, feel free to check it out [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/marker/Marker.js)

As an in-browser javascript library, I've never come across a situation where leaflet sent data. In fact, the only thing you really need an internet connection for in leaflet is to get map tiles/images.